# Time complexity about adding matrices

Tags: matrix, sum, time-complexity

I'm having a hard time trying to solve an algorithm question about summing up matrices. The problem I'm struggling with is as below.

There is a N × N matrix A initialized by arbitrary values. Given 5 values R1, R2, C1, C2 and V , there is a program like below. (1 ≤ R1,R2,C1,C2 ≤ N integers, V : a real value)

```
for k := 1 to N do
    read (R1,R2,C1,C2, V);
    for i := R1 to R2 do
        for j := C1 to C2 do
            A[i][j] := A[i][j] + V ;
        end
    end
end
```

Currently, time complexity is O(N^3), because all three loops can run at most N times.
And I need to print out all values in the matrix after all updates are done.
The question is, how can I decrease its time complexity less than O(N^3)?

I really can't figure out a way so I'm asking here hoping to get an advice.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize this using a technique called [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum). Instead of updating all the values in the submatrix `[R1, R2] x [C1, C2]` immediately, you can just update the corners and then propagate the changes in a single pass later.

Here's the idea:

1. When you read `(R1, R2, C1, C2, V)`, update `A[R1][C1] += V`, `A[R1][C2+1] -= V`, `A[R2+1][C1] -= V`, and `A[R2+1][C2+1] += V`.
2. After all updates, compute the prefix sum twice: once row-wise and then column-wise to get the final updated values.

This way, each update operation is O(1) and the final propagation step is O(N^2), making the overall time complexity O(N^2).

Pseudo-code:

```
# Step 1: Update corners
for k := 1 to N do
    read (R1, R2, C1, C2, V)
    A[R1][C1] += V
    A[R1][C2+1] -= V
    A[R2+1][C1] -= V
    A[R2+1][C2+1] += V
end

# Step 2: Propagate changes
# Row-wise
for i := 1 to N do
    for j := 2 to N do
        A[i][j] += A[i][j-1]
    end
end

# Column-wise
for j := 1 to N do
    for i := 2 to N do
        A[i][j] += A[i-1][j]
    end
end
```

Comment: thx u truly r a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77187353/12671057) (in a duplicate question) (and [Sash's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77179179/12671057)) but only horizontal differences. Makes the additions slower, but saves vertical pre/post-processings, and is the same O(N^2) overall.

In Python ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVK9TsMwEJYY_RQnsSRNg3AACVVkYm4GBpYoQoY41FUaR7ajwLOwdIF3gpEn4WynTShL8XC5fHffdz_220f7alay2W7fO1PF118n3yWvwMigEkqbOdRMm3BBAI_iplMNKNY882k4oiGxpFL2zT9oMZ1DPFBF03YmcDZ19jd3w1oMIs_nhWe6rQV-PVmvZB8MhEoqULLHRFjmdFF41J5WoUIww6DFQzJiISGn8KQ4MxxYUzo9FBBGsBpLGyVeSAYpXJEl2jw_L2AGQYZju3IPtpifzmIF8f1YUYOwxpzNTsbmC5uPC8bxs0nXawu7FWZzSMKx8WUuinxdQJwObkwLK667R68KrCyxWdlop68NU-ZvjTvZ4x_aZA63sqbOon_P6o7jXMNq9_3s2hx5hz1ZlQKi1EvsY6JyynAD2UiYkpKIumkGGo6iuDZS8WO3hHAywtMdRYc7sldpVtxW6GozXI1_6sOL337SBC4ggUug5EjPM38A) with additional code for demonstration):

```py
# transform matrix
for i in to(1, N):
    for j in down(N, 2):
        M[i][j] -= M[i][j-1]

# submatrix additions
for start in to(1, N):
    Row1, Row2, Col1, Col2, Value = input()
    for i in to(Row1, Row2):
        M[i][Col1] += Value
        if Col2 < N:
            M[i][Col2+1] -= Value
 
# restore matrix
for i in to(1, N):
    for j in to(2, N):
        M[i][j] += M[i][j-1]
```

[Matt's likewise in Python at Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVO9TsMwEB7Y_BQnsSS0QSSAhCo6MTcDA0sUIUMc6iqNI9tR4VlYusCD8BbwNNzZ6U9oKyDDxTl_33ef75zX9-bFTlW9XL61toyuvo4-ClGCVUEptbFDqLix4YgBPlrYVtegef0ktrcHcciIVKhF_Q9aFA8h6qiyblobuDh2sc-d8wY3kedx4alpKolvTzZTtQg6Qqk0aLVAIEyyeJT7LD2NRoXgBDcpH7JNLmTsGB614FYArwunhwLSSl5haavlM0thDJdsgjHLznI4gSDFY7ty91TMn45yOfN-SNRi2iBmvpIhvCQ8NhiPn265nlHatTAdQhJujE8ymWezHKJxt4zifCP0k7GW6lfYFUIV_CCXpn3w9oAXBZ5a1cbpG8u13ZW6VQv8wpgM4UZVsYu4vuNVK7BB3YyYL0noPCNcDoOxB7ktWToeXEO6bXGNTwaxs9pjUNU9DMJ2NQ4x3GQPFFzRXcmNSWyNFsYqLfaNL9kzvsM9H2z3_Ldb0FfflenuAI2OrqqdCjLaVra7ev5X7v7o5WecwDkkcAEx--PKM78B)