# Is this possible to reduce O(N^3) time complexity of submatrix additions in N*N Matrix?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication

There is a N * N Matrix M. and It is initialized with random values.

And there are input Row1, Row2, Col1, Col2, Value.

and there is a pseudo code below.

```
for start = 1 to N:

    input(Row1, Row2, Col1, Col2, Value)

    for i = Row1 to Row2:

        for j = Col1 to Col2:

            M[i][j] = M[i][j] + Value
```

a loop that iterates from start = 1 to N.

Inside the loop, you have an input function or command that takes five parameters: Row1, Row2, Col1, Col2, and Value.

After getting the input, you have nested loops. The first loop iterates over rows from Row1 to Row2, and the second loop iterates over columns from Col1 to Col2. These nested loops are used to access and update specific elements of the 2D matrix M.

you're updating the matrix M at position [i][j] by adding the Value to the current value at that position.

The purpose of this code is updating a submatrix of a 2D matrix M with a given value Value. The specific submatrix to be updated is defined by the input parameters Row1, Row2, Col1, and Col2.

We know this program takes O(N^3).
But i want to make it faster like less than O(N^3).

If you give me any way or solution with details, im really appreciate it.
Thank you

I tried to look lots of algorithms but i couldn't find to make it less than O(N^3)

Comment: The short version is: yes, but the constant-factor overhead is so high that you need improbably large matrices to make it worthwhile. Also, this is not really a Python question or anything related to any specific programming language, really. Please see the linked duplicate.

Comment: the range of N is 5 <= N <= 100 !

Comment: @harold OP said O(n^3) so I assumed matrix multiplication and didn't really look at the code. At this level of demonstrated understanding we should probably not expect a clearer question.

Comment: yes that's what i said!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in O(N<sup>2</sup>), where N is one dimension of the matrix *and* the number of submatrix additions.

1. First, you transform into 'differential' form, replacing each element with the difference between it and the elements above and to the left of it.  We will transform it back later.
2. Now you can do each of your submatrix additions in constant time, because each value you add to the matrix will affect *all* of the elements below and to the right of it.
3. Then transform the matrix back.

In your style of pseudocode, it look like this:

```
# transform matrix

for i = 1 to N:
    for j = N down to 2:
        M[i][j] -= M[i][j-1]
for i = N down to 2:
    for j = 1 to N:
        M[i][j] -= M[i-1][j]

# submatrix additions

for start = 1 to N:

    input(Row1, Row2, Col1, Col2, Value)

    M[Row1][Col1] += Value
    if Col2 < N:
        M[Row1][Col2+1] -= Value
    if Row2 < N:
        M[Row2+1][Col1] -= Value
    if Row2 < N and Col2 < N
        M[Row2+1][Col2+1] += Value
 
# restore matrix

for i = 2 to N:
    for j = 1 to N:
        M[i][j] += M[i-1][j]
for i = 1 to N:
    for j = 2 to N:
        M[i][j] += M[i][j-1]
```

Comment: Seems like overkill. Difference along one axis suffices. Then each addition takes O(N) instead of O(1), but overall it's the same O(N^2).

Comment: That's quite true, but I think it's more useful and interesting to learn the 2-dimensional technique.

Comment: And apparently you're not the only one. Someone else had asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77179136/12671057) a day earlier and someone else answered with the same two-axis method...

Comment: Just curious: Did you write the "transform matrix" part directly? I had no trouble understanding the other two parts, but I find "transform matrix" hard to grasp except as inverse of "restore matrix" :-)

Comment: Yes, both transforms are separable convolutions, and I think of them as the product of the transforms along each axis.  The language "difference between the elements above and to the left of it" is awkward, so I tried to write the differentiation in the way it would come out if you mechanically inverted the integration.

Comment: Thanks. I have very little practice with convolutions, and I can imagine this becomes easy with more experience.